# How do I initialize the ol.map using my own class myMap (using inheritance), in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, dictionary, openlayers-3

I am working on a GIS API and I am changing from OpenLayers 2 to Openlayers 3.

I want to instantiate the ol.map using my own class, like this:

**myMap.js**

```
goog.inherits(myMap, ol.map);
```

**index.html**

```
new myMap({
    layers: [{ ... }]
    ...
})
```

Unfortunately, the map doesn't show up in the browser. Nothing happens.

Do I have to execute some function in the myMap init, like in OpenLayers 2? Something like "this.prototype.parent.initialize ..."??

Thank you.

João

**EDIT 1**

This is how ol.map instantiation normally works:
http://jsfiddle.net/joaorodr84/SrBWL/

This is how I want it to works, using my own "myMap" class:
http://jsfiddle.net/joaorodr84/T2Bet/11/

Comment: Hi João, any chance of a bit more context? jsFiddle or something similar.

Comment: Hi @John Barça. Thank you for commenting. I'm a newbie with jsFiddle. Nevertheless, I tried to explain my problem using two fiddles. I hope I made myself a bit more clear. :) See the EDIT 1, please.

Comment: You may need to instantiate the superclass from within your extended class. See Example, https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/introduction?csw=1#oop

Answer (score 2):

If you can't (or don't want to) use ol-whitespace.js and the goog library, here is an alternative solution:

```
Map = function (options){
    ol.Map.call(this, options);
};
Map.prototype = Object.create(ol.Map.prototype);
```

L

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved by using the ol-whitespace.js instead of ol.js because the good methods are not exported in the compressed build.

Additionally, the code looks like this:

```
myMap = function(options) {
    goog.base(this, options);
};
goog.inherits(myMap, ol.Map);
```

It works! ;)

Comment: Useful, I am just starting to learn OL3, which is very different to OL2.